# python- dulwich only working in interpreter, but not as a script

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, python-3.x, dulwich

I am trying to use dulwich to access my git repositories. I have followed the documentation and installed it as required, and then tried running this simple script:

```
>>> from dulwich.repo import Repo
>>> r = Repo(<path/to/my/repo>)
>>> r.head()
>>> c = r[r.head()]
>>> c
>>> c.message
```

When I type that line by line in the Python interpreter, it works fine, and I get the intended results.

However, when I create a script with the same commands, and then try running it from terminal using `python script-name.py`, I get no results at all.

And finally, when I run the same script in PyCharm, I get an error that says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dulwich.repo'; 'dulwich' is not a package`.

Any idea what is happening here, because I can't find anything helpful?

Comment: You may not have set your interpreter correctly in PyCharm. Go to `Preference > Project > Project Interpreter` and then select the interpreter you are using, whether that's system python or a virtualenv

Comment: __Where__ and __how__ do you launch _python_ (what  `set` or `export` commands are you using (if any)). Apparently, it's a _PYTHONPATH_ related problem (and how it gets set in various envs e.g. _PyCharm_ (personal opinion: a great _IDE_ )).

Comment: @mattjegan I will check the project interpreter, but if that is the problem, it would be really weird, because I have already written multiple scripts in PyCharm and had no problem running it. Anyway, I will update you when I get a chance to try it.

Comment: @CristiFati I am not using any `set` or `export` commands. When I launch the interpreter, I just type `python` or `python3.6` in terminal. In PyCharm, all I used to do was to just run scripts using Alt+Shift+F10, and it just works, but I will check to see how is the PYTHONPATH is set in PyCharm. But I have also tried running `python script.py` from terminal, and, although I didn't get the error message, I didn't get any output.